# Tar command adds permission number to filenames

Tags: windows, file, permissions, numbers, tar

I did "tar -cvf mydata.tar mydata/".
Then, I copied it to my window PC and untar it.

Now, I can see that some files have strange file name.
Original : mypicture.png
Untar    : mypicture.png0000664

I can see that certain number is added to file name, like a "0000664"
I guess it's a permission number of linux.

I don't know why these numbers are added to the filename..
Could someone please tell me what makes it happens?

I did

- "tar -cvf mydata.tar mydata/"
- copy it to window PC and untar

I expect

- all files have proper name.

Actual result

- certain number (permission number) is added to some files.

Comment: This is OFF topic. Not programming related.